# Amazon Web Services Objective-C SDK to Sign a Query Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a signature for AWS signature as described in this doc.
The Doc has Java code i need equivalent Objective-c Code

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html

I have made a class  AWSRequest

```
//  AWSRequest.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "../AmazonServiceRequest.h"

@interface AWSRequest : AmazonServiceRequest

- (void)makeSignature;

@end
```

Implement

```
//  AWSRequest.m
#import "AWSRequest.h"
#import <AWSiOSSDK/AWSRuntime.h>
#import "AmazonAuthUtils.h"

@implementation AWSRequest

-(void)makeSignature
{
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    float finalTime = timeInterval;
    NSString *sendTimeStamp = F(@"%0.f%@", finalTime , @"000");
[self setParameterValue:credentials.accessKey forKey:@"AWSAccessKeyId"];
    [self setParameterValue:@"2"                                        forKey:@"SignatureVersion"];
    [self setParameterValue:sendTimeStamp  forKey:@"Timestamp"];
    [self setParameterValue:@"HmacSHA256"                               forKey:@"SignatureMethod"];

    NSData   *dataToSign = [[AmazonAuthUtils getV2StringToSign:[NSURL URLWithString:self.endpoint] request:self] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *signature  = [AmazonAuthUtils HMACSign:dataToSign withKey:credentials.secretKey usingAlgorithm:kCCHmacAlgSHA256];

    [self setParameterValue:signature forKey:@"Signature"];
}
```

Then the following methods calls the service

```
 NSString *accessKey = @"Q_____O";
        NSString *secretKey = @"2____2";

        AmazonCredentials *credentials       = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:accessKey withSecretKey:secretKey];
AmazonServiceRequest *serviceRequest = [[AmazonServiceRequest alloc] init];
    serviceRequest.credentials           = credentials;
AWSRequest *request                  = [[AWSRequest alloc] init];
    request.credentials                  = credentials;
    request.delegate                     = self;
    [request makeSignature];
```

Is there something wrong in the code ? Like using the TimeStamp etc as i am always getting Unauthorized error from web service.

Following links might be helpful

- http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/07/talking-to-amazon-web-services/
- http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx296UMHAW17ZOV/Using-Different-AWS-Regions-with-the-AWS-Mobile-SDKs
- http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx31X75XISXHRH8/Managing-Credentials-in-Mobile-Applications

Answer (score 2):

Which service are you using?  Most services now require [signature version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

You link to our blog, but are you aware of the [AWS SDK for iOS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/)? Even if you don't want to use the SDK directly, the source code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) so you can compare your implementation versus our official one.

Comment: thks a lot but my client has ver2. I have used the AWS SDK for iOS using pod 'AWSiOSSDK', '1.7.1', i dont have problem using SDk but the generated signature is not correct. Maybe the endpoint is no valid. Is my method of using AmazonCredentials correct. Do you have any objectiv-c sample project which use signature generated to make AWS request. If so plz do post link to sample iOS project.

Comment: @BishalGhimire There are numerous samples in our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples). I will again ask, what service are you actually calling and why are you generating your own signature if you are using the AWS SDK for iOS?

Comment: I need to user ASWSignature for connecting to cloudsearch, but I am having a really difficult time getting it to return data. Any Suggestions @bob kinney?

Comment: This is really hard to understand.  The signature version 4 documentation has no mention of what objective-c function to call if we want to perform the hash.  It just blabs on about what the underlying HTTP GET request calls are, but Apple iOS handles NSURL just fine.  I just need a simple API to get the signature, not a long spiel about how to implement "canonical requests" and low-level HTTP calls.  As far as I'm concerned, constructing the REST API query call is already a request.